# Morris.js View Full date with time

Tags: javascript, jquery, morris.js

I have a problem because that i make dynamic response of back-end.
my code generated is:

```
    new Morris.Line({
            // ID of the element in which to draw the chart.
            element: 'myfirstchart',
            // Chart data records -- each entry in this array corresponds to a point on
            // the chart.
            data: [

            { year: '2015-05-13 14:47:56', 
            value: 18 }

            { year: '2015-05-13 00:07:22', 
            value: 21 }

            { year: '2015-05-12 00:07:22', 
            value: 23 }

            { year: '2015-05-11 17:14:49', 
            value: 22 }

            { year: '2015-05-11 00:07:31', 
            value: 22 }

            { year: '2015-05-10 17:59:56', 
            value: 26 }

            { year: '2015-05-10 06:02:49', 
            value: 27 }

            { year: '2015-05-10 04:46:30', 
            value: 888 }
                    ],

            xkey: 'year',
            ykeys: ['value'],
            labels: ['Value']
            });

            </script>
```

but i dont make correctly format on date
what to do? in xkey what the default format to accept it?
i need the DAYS and mounth if is possible

Comment: also i try period in xkey but dont function

Comment: You render your code via PHP right?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
new Morris.Line({

    element: 'myfirstchart',

    data: [

    { year: '2015-05-13 14:47:56', 
    value: 18 }

    { year: '2015-05-13 00:07:22', 
    value: 21 }

    { year: '2015-05-12 00:07:22', 
    value: 23 }

    { year: '2015-05-11 17:14:49', 
    value: 22 }

    { year: '2015-05-11 00:07:31', 
    value: 22 }

    { year: '2015-05-10 17:59:56', 
    value: 26 }

    { year: '2015-05-10 06:02:49', 
    value: 27 }

    { year: '2015-05-10 04:46:30', 
    value: 888 }
            ],

    xkey: 'year',
    ykeys: ['value'],
    parseTime: false,
    labels: ['Value'],
    pointSize: 2,
    hideHover: 'auto',
    resize: true
});
```